# What happen first, casting or shifting bits [C++]

Tags: c++

What's happening first here in C++, shift or casting?

```
(dword)header[2]<<8
```

Comment: Isn't that a wrong way to cast in C++ ??

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Just google [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: C++ doesn't depend on operator precedence, and there are a few cases (but not this one) where it doesn't work.  As a general rule, however: unary operators are evaluated before binary ones, and postfix operators before prefix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From here [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) you can see that `bitwise shift` has lower precedence than `type cast`. So that is equivalent to:

```
((dword) (header[2])) << 8
```

Always use parentheses for things that are not clear, even if you check that it is actually ok, because it improves code readability. (you might not want to enclose the subscript like I did to emphasis all the precedences here, but use the other parenthesis).

Comment: Why not use c++ cast (i.e. static_cast) instead? Increases readability and clarity of intent.

Comment: @AriaPahlavan I just added parenthesis to the OP original expression.